# CircuiTikZ error: Package pgfkeys Error

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I am new to CircuiTikZ and I am trying to start with very simple diagrams. I have been given a preamble and the relevant parts of it for CircuiTikZ seem to be

```
\usepackage[americanresistors,americaninductors]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
    
    \tikzset{circuit declare symbol = ac current source}
    \tikzset{
              ac current source IEC graphic/.style={
                circuit symbol lines,
                circuit symbol size = width 2 height 2,
                shape = generic circle IEC,
                /pgf/generic circle IEC/before background={
                  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.8pt}{0pt}}
                  \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{0.4pt}{0.4pt}}
                  \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{0.4pt}{-0.4pt}}
                  \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{0.4pt}{-0.4pt}}
                  \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{0.4pt}{0.4pt}}
                  \pgfusepath{stroke}
                },
                transform shape
              }
    }
```

I read the CircuiTikZ documentation and wrote this

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{preamble}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\title{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\linespread{1}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\ifthenelse{\value{page}=0}{}{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw
(0,0) to [short, *-] (6,0)
to [R=$R_1$] (6,4);
\end{circuitikz}

\fancyhead{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\end{document}
```

This is the end result I get.

[image]

The error I get on Overleaf is as follows.

*Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/$R_1$' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.*

Not sure what the issue is. Tried checking out similar posts but couldn't figure out a solution. Any help would be really appreciated :).

**Edit:** Extended `circuitikz` code snippet to show `document` environment.

Comment: Please extend your `circuitikz`-env only code snippet to a complete example which starts with `\documentclass` and contains one `document` environment.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the post to show this.

Comment: After removing `fancyhdr` staff and replacing non-existent package `preamble` with `circuitikz`, your example compiles without errors.

Comment: In your document example you not load `circuitikz` package. Ti*k*Z libraries for electrical schemas are no compatible with `circuitikz`. For their use you need to load `\usepackage[compatibility]{circuitikz}` and than use `\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]` (see subsection An example with the compatibility option),circuitikz  package documentation,  page 214). However, it is better to not mix them.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. I have changed my preamble by removing the `circuits ee IEC` library, and it complies fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In drawing of electrical circuits don't mix syntax from Ti*k*Z libraries and `circuitikz`. If you for some reason forced to do this, then consult documentation for `circuitikz` package, where this is shortly addressed in subsection "10.8 An example with the compatibility option" (Note, in example is minor error: in line 7 should be `\usepackage[compatibility]{circuitikz}`).

A MWE (Minimal working Example) for your simple circuit using `circuitikz` package is:

```
\documentclass[12pt, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
\draw   (0,0) to [short, *-] (6,0)
              to [R=$R_1$] (6,4);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

It works fine and generate the following image of circuit:

[image]

If you refer European style of drawing circuits, than add option `[european]` to `circuitikz`:

```
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
```

in MWE preamble or

```
    \begin{circuitikz}[european]
```

In bot cases you will get:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have implemented your MWE and it works fine.